# In Postman - How to encrypt/decrypt value in Headers/Body ->change some keys' value->put back

Tags: encryption, postman, environment

How to encrypt/decrypt value in Headers/Body in Postman API then change some keys' values and decrypt/encrypt again and put it back in Postman API for automation?
Also put some values in the decrypted content from the Environment.

Expecting to run a call successfully

Comment: Can you see this guide? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)